# How to build OpenCV package?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just started using ROS and completed some basic tutorials in the Wiki.
I have created a workspace and tried building some packages. So far so good.
It has been a while since i did anything technical, and have used OpenCV in the past , i thought it could be a good way to start learning ROS .

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to use the OpenCV package in ROS ? How do i build it and use it from inside the sandbox workspace ? Should i pull it from the repo and use **rosmake** or build it at the original installation path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45694/how-to-build-opencv-package-?/) by [bhala](https://answers.ros.org/users/3369/bhala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV is a system dependency as of electric, so you'll have to install it separately rather than using rosmake. You can find [installation instructions on the openCV website](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide).

To use openCV with ROS, you'll want to use the cv_bridge package of the [vision_opencv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv) stack.  It basically converts openCV data structures into ROS messages. You can find tutorials for using cv_bridge [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1